# Contents are showing above the header

Tags: module, forms, admin-controller, page-content

I have just created a new module and in controller echo some text so it is showing above the header how i can wrap it under the header as the other module showd:

Following is my Controller code:

```
 class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_ReviewController extends   Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
     {

      public function indexAction()
        {
    // "Fetch" display
        $this->loadLayout();

    // "Inject" into display
    // THe below example will not actualy show anything since the core/template is empty
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template'));

    echo "Hello developer...";

    // "Output" display
    $this->renderLayout();
}   
}
```

and Also I want to create a form here that will same data to database how i can do that too

Answer (score 0):

When you echo something inside the controller that will be rendered to the browser before magento render the output.

You can try something like below:

```
$this->loadLayout()
    ->_addContent(
        $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('core/template')
            ->setTemplate('mymodule/form.phtml') //form.phtml should be inside the app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/mymodule/form.phtml
    )
    ->renderLayout();
```